# Please help me to prove this inequality: $|x|+|y|≥|x+y|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

Please help me to prove the following inequality:

> $|x|+|y|\geq|x+y|$

in which $x$  and $y$  are real numbers.

Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Is this a cardinality argument (as hinted at by the tags), or is this an algebraic inequality with real numbers?  or is it complex?

Comment: What kind of objects are $w$ and $z$? Real numbers? Complex numbers? Vectors? Something else? Also, what does this have to do with elementary-set-theory?

Comment: Ok hint: Draw a parallelogram with v and w as it sides. The diagonal is v+w (assuming it is about vectors). Use a compass to map v and w on the diagonal so that they don't overlap. The diagonal is running short, isn't it?

Comment: You should really tell as what z and w are. The tag ([tag:algebraic-geometry]) is definitely not correct. ([tag:absolute-value]) might be suitable. If you are talking about complex numbers, you can add ([tag:complex-numbers]). If you mean real numbers, then ([tag:real-analysis]) might be a good tag.

Comment: "You should really tell as what z and w are." Yes! What are they? "Numbers"? As in $|-5+1| < |-5| + |1|$? Or something else? Judging from your other questions, you should know that this is important.

Comment: It seems like your question lacks context and details.  You should add them a bit more to make it understandable and solvable.

Comment: ${+++++++++++++}$

Comment: Hello, Software! Good to see you. I haven't been around as much, either, as I've been ill. But getting well again!

Comment: Do not worry @amWhy 
 We all know your answers are excellent.
 I'm sure your answers is really help users.

Comment: @amWhy: are you online? I design this for you ;)  I hope you like this http://s1.picofile.com/file/7898592361/flashdesign.jpg

Comment: @Software (flashdesign). Thank you!! That's so sweet. I love it, and have downloaded the image :^)

Comment: @amWhy I'm glad you love it :) I wish you the best <3

Comment: You are quite talented! Keep up the good work! - And you can send a few upvotes $\uparrow$ my way, too ;-)

Comment: Thank you @amWhy Yes, of course my dear ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $w$ and $z$ are real numbers, $w,z \in \mathbb{R}$, (and not sets, as implied by your [elementary-set-theory](/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory) tag) then there are two cases: Either $w$ and $z$ have the same sign (both negative or both non-negative) or they don't (one is negative and the other non-negative). If $w$ and $z$ have the same sign, what happens to $w+z$? What if they have opposite signs? What's the largest $|w+z|$ can be?

Hint: If $w$ and $z$ are complex numbers, $w,z\in \mathbb{C}$, then let $w=r_1 e^{i\theta_1}$, $z=r_2 e^{i\theta_2}$. What happens to $|w+z|$ if $\theta_1 \equiv \theta_2\ (\operatorname{mod}\ 2\pi)$? What if $\theta_1 \not \equiv \theta_2\ (\operatorname{mod}\ 2\pi)$? What is the largest $|w+z|$ can be?

Hint: If $w$ and $z$ are sets, as not-stated in your question, by implied by your tag, then two cases occur again. Case 1: suppose $w$ and $z$ share at least one element. Case 2: suppose $w$ and $z$ do not share any elements. What is the largest $|w+z|$ can be?

Hint: If $\mathfrak{w}$ and $\mathfrak{z}$ are ideals of a ring $R$, then what you say is not true.

Meta hint: You should include more information in your questions.

Comment: @faranak50 OK, I removed the '-1' I had given you. Maybe it didn't occur to you that $w$ and $z$ could be other things. I hope I didn't give you too hard of a time.

Answer (score 3):

geometrical interpretation:  sum of the lengths of any two sides of triangle  is  greater than the length of the remaining side
and  $|x+y|=|x|^2+|y|^2-2|x||y|\cos(\alpha)$ $\alpha$ is angle between $x$ and $y$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Considering $w,z$ are complex numbers,

$|w+z|^2=(w+z)(\bar{w}+\bar{z})=|w|^2+|z|^2+(w\bar{z}+z\bar{w})$

$(|w|+|z|)^2=|w|^2+|z|^2+2|w||z|$

As $|w+z|,(|w|+|z|)\ge 0$ so to prove $|w+z|\le|w|+|z|$ it will suffice to prove $|w+z|^2\le(|w|+|z|)^2$

So it will suffice to prove

$(w\bar{z}+z\bar{w})\le2|w||z|$

Let $w=x+iy,z=a+ib$

Then $w\bar{z}=2(xa+yb)$

and $|w||z|=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2)}$

So we are now reduced to proving,

$\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2)}\ge(xa+yb)$ and it follows from cauchy schwarz inequality with equality occuring when $\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=k\Rightarrow w=kz$

Comment: ... If $w$ and $z$ are complex numbers then it follows directly from the [cosine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Comment: I guess this is much elementary than that.

Comment: Yeah that's true. I think they were meant to be $w,z\in \mathbb{R}$. However maybe what I said is helpful for you, considering that your proof was more complicated than just trigonometry?

Comment: Your proof is a good one.... but I think this is easy to understand(by the way i dont think its complicated).

Comment: Now I think the tag is right.@faranak50

Comment: you are welcome @faranak50

Answer (score 1):

Another answer

[image]

so

$|z+w|\leq |z|+|w|$

Comment: +1 Nicely done. (Feel free to upvote my posts if and when you think they are helpful; just don't "upvote" too many posts at one time, and not too many posts in one day). Hope you are doing well, dear friend! ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry you feel sick! Yuck!

Comment: Given the course of events in the past, that would really NOT be wise, since it seems the moderators may suspect that he has a second account with your user name. So *any* upvotes from your account may look suspicious. Your best teacher appreciates your admiration, but in my opinion, this is one place *not* to show that admiration by upvoting his answers.